# published properties not showing in designer

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, delphi-10.2-tokyo

In previous versions of Delphi, my custom Form showed its published properties.

However, I'm running into an issue with Delphi 10.2 Tokyo. Specifically, I'm not seeing a good way to call the appropriate method found in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22857186/published-property-not-shown-in-object-inspector#22878418).

To sum it up, a call to `RegisterCustomModule()` is needed, however, in the `DesignIntf` unit described [here](http://www.marcocantu.com/ddh/ddh15/ddh15e.htm), there is no `TCustomModule` (there is `TBaseCustomModule` and `TCustomModuleClass`, though), also the base custom module inherits from `TInterfacedObject`, which `TForm` does not (using FMX as my framework).

What is the correct method for registering a FMX Form to show published properties in the latest version of Delphi?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
uses DesignEditors;

type
   TMySpecialForm = class(TCustomForm)
   end;


RegisterCustomModule(TMySpecialForm, TCustomModule);
```

`RegisterCustomModule` takes 2 parameters: `ComponentBaseClass` and `CustomModuleClass`.  The first is your custom form class, which will, of course, be derived from `TCustomForm`.  The second is a class that will be used by the designer.  This class must do 2 things: derive from `TBaseCustomModule` (in `DesignIntf` unit) and implement the `ICustomModule` interface.  Take a look at the comment in the `DesignEditors` unit, around line 502.

The `TCustomModule` class is provided for you to use if you have no behavior other than the default to add to your custom form at design time.

If you do want some kind of custom behavior for your form while in the designer, say, a pop-up menu with various property-setting commands, you would create your own `TCustomModule` class:

```
uses DesignEditors;

type
    TMySpecialFormDesigner = class(TCustomModule, ICustomModule)
        function GetVerb(Index: Integer): string; override;
        function GetVerbCount: Integer; override;
    end;

RegisterCustomModule(TMySpecialForm, TMySpecialFormDesigner);
```

Comment: thank you Dave, I understood the requirements, but I did not know that the TCustomModule class was declared in the DesignEditors unit. Also, appreciate the example.